# Why labelWidth: 'auto' is hidding the radiofield?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6-modern, extjs6.5

I am trying to wrap the `label` of a `radiofield` but i don't want to set fixed `width` and `labelWidth` because of the responsiveness of the view. But when i set the `labelWidth` to **auto** the `input element` gets hidden.

Am I doing it wrong? Thanks.

Add the code below inside the launch function of a sencha fiddle and select Ext JS 6.5.3.57 - Triton [Modern] from the dropdown.

```
Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
        fullscreen: true,
        layout: {
          type: 'vbox',
          align: 'stretch',
          pack: 'start'
        },
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'panel',
                //flex: 1,
                //height: 100,
                layout: {
                  type: 'hbox',
                  align: 'stretch',
                  pack: 'start'
                },
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'radiofield',
                        flex: 3,
                        //width: '100%',
                        label: 'afglngfsdlgkdslfkjsdlfkjdslkfjdslfkjsdlfkjsdlkfjsdlkfjsdlkfjdslkfjsdlkfjsdlkfjdslkfjldskfjsldkfjlsdkfjlsdkfjlsdkfjlsdkfjlkdsjflsdkjflsdkjflsdkjflsdkjflsdkjfklslfkdfjsldfk',
                        labelAlign: 'right',
                        labelWrap: true,
                        labelWidth: 'auto',
                        style: 'word-wrap: break-word;',
                        name : 'color',
                        value: 'red',
                        checked: true
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        flex: 1,
                        margin: '0 0 0 10'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[labelWrap](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/modern/Ext.field.Radio.html#cfg-labelWrap)** `true` to allow the label to wrap. If set to `false`, the label will be truncated with an ellipsis.

The CSS **`word-wrap`** property defines whether the browser is allowed to line break within words when a word is too long to fit within its container.

Here is **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2ee3)**, I have created a demo. I hope this will help/guide you to achieve your requirement.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.create({
            xtype: 'panel',
            fullscreen: true,
            layout: {
                type: 'vbox',
                align: 'stretch',
                pack: 'start'
            },
            items: [{
                xtype: 'panel',
                layout: {
                    type: 'hbox',
                    align: 'stretch',
                    pack: 'start'
                },
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'radiofield',
                    flex: 3,
                    label: 'afglngfsdlgkdslfkjsdlfkjdslkfjdslfkjsdlfkjsdlkfjsdlkfjsdlkfjdslkfjsdlkfjsdlkfjdslkfjldskfjsldkfjlsdkfjlsdkfjlsdkfjlsdkfjlkdsjflsdkjflsdkjflsdkjflsdkjflsdkjfklslfkdfjsldfk',
                    labelAlign: 'right',
                    labelWidth: 'auto',
                    name: 'color',
                    value: 'red',
                    checked: true
                }, {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    placeHolder: 'example',
                    flex: 1,
                    margin: '0 0 0 10'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'radiofield',
                    flex: 1,
                    label: 'The word-break CSS property specifies whether or not the browser should insert line breaks wherever the text would otherwise overflow its content box.',
                    labelAlign: 'right',
                    labelWrap: true,
                    labelWidth: 'auto',
                    name: 'color',
                    value: 'red'
                }]
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried your code using Ext JS 6.5.3.57 - Triton [Modern]? You will see that the actual input element is hidden. Obviously it's another sencha bug.

Comment: Yes I have seen with ExtJS 6.5.x. Input is hidden when we are setting `labelWidth: 'auto'`. So may it's framework or need to check in details.
Currently which version using ?

Comment: the latest. 6.5.3.57.

Comment: if you set it with percentage it works `labelWidth: '95%'` for example. But it doesn't look good.

Comment: Yes I have tried in my [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2ee3). if I see look is also good. Can you provide screenshot where you think look is not good ?

Comment: it depends on the device. if you use developer tools on google chrome check it using nexus 7. When you set it with percentage the space that the label takes has to do with the device width.

Comment: Ok try this `labelWidth: 'calc(100% - 22px)',` 
Please refer this [FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2ee3)

Comment: i'll give it a try and i'll let you know. Thank you Nerendra.

Comment: Sure I hope this will help you :)

Comment: your `labelWidth: 'calc(100% - 22px)'` fix worked. please update your answer.